# PublishingStartDate empty even though the page is published

Tags: development, publishing-page, spsitedataquery, query

I've been through the typical publish/approve process and have, seemingly, successfully published a page (I've checked it's approval status in the manage content and structure section of the site which says approved. Does this mean it's published?).

However, when I run the following query (which does bring back the page in question), the **PublishingStartDate** is always empty:

```
//query.ViewFields = @"<FieldRef Name=""PublishingStartDate"" /><FieldRef Name=""Author"" />";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That field only applies to pages that are/were published on a scheduled date and time and it should be empty for Pages that are published immediately.

Comment: Thanks a LOT Dave! Very helpful response. So with this in mind, is there a field that holds the value of the published date if it has been published immediately?

Comment: The CAML for that should be `<FieldRef Name=\"_Level\" /><Value Type=\"Integer\">1</Value>`